# Another RPM dependency issue...

Tags: rpm

I have an RPM that provides two shared libraries.

The way that they are built means that the second one is linked against the first.

They are built in separate directories and when the second library is built it references the first one as ../dir1/objs/blah.so.

This build fine.

However, when I try to install the RPM it gives a failed dependency error, complaining the the first library is missing. I am guessing that this is because it is only looking in /usr/lib64 for lib1 and it's not there yet as the install hasn't completed.

Is there something I can do to stop this error apart from using the --nodeps switch?

R.

Answer (score 0):

If both are provided properly, installing them in the same RPM transaction is perfectly cromulent.